# Image recognition, how to start out

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, image-recognition

As part of my dissertation for my BSc degree, I have to utilize image recognition on a video feed.

I have identified openCV and Tensorflow - specifically the Inception trained model - as two options, however I wouldn't know how to go on from there. Basically what I'll need is to pass a string such as "keys" and if one of the top 5 outcomes is "keys" get a boolean back.

Just to mention, I did a python course online since both use python. Also I have pretty solid experience with Java, we've been using it the past two years in our uni.

Note that I do **not** need to create a whole new image recognition system, I need to use one to tell me what my camera is seeing.

Also, while it is video, I think that it will be tougher to process the actual video feed. What I thought of is to pick out 1 of 30 frames (assuming a 30fps video feed) and run image recognition on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the constraints on the objects being viewed by the image recognition system's camera in terms of size, distance, brightness, movement, etc.?

Comment: @JohnH I don't quite get what you're asking, but I have a feeling I should. Are you asking what the viewing circumstances will be, or what the image recognition system needs?

Edit: In the first case, it will be indoors, and well lit. The camera will be moving around until the given object is found.

Comment: Your scope seems rather broad in terms of what objects can be viewed and identified. Your work load might be more reasonable if you were to limit the type of objects that you are trying to identify. Once that is defined, then it will be easier to provide answers towards that goal.

Comment: @JohnH Why does the scope matter in this situation? As for limiting objects would "household objects" be a good limit? :D Are you talking about having to train the model for various objects? I was under the impression that Inception is a trained model.

Answer (score 2):

Your project should be fairly straightforward if you read through [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html), and specifically the section, "Usage with Python API". The top N outcomes produced by `classify_image.py` are converted into human readable text [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py#L163) in this block of code:

```
top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
    score = predictions[node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

For your example, you'd want to set `FLAGS.num_top_predictions` to 5 and you'd want to accumulate the top 5 `human_string` values as something like:

```
top_k_strings = []
top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
    top_k_strings.append(human_string)
    score = predictions[node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
```

Finally, you could check if "keys" is one of the top 5 strings that imagenet produced and pass back a boolean as

```
return "keys" in top_k_strings
```

Also if you're interested in the full list of human-readable categories you can find them [here](https://github.com/atong01/Imagenet-Tensorflow/blob/master/model/imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt)

With respect to video, you're probably right that you'll have to subsample the video sequence to keep up with the frame rate. Some experimentation and timing tests will give you a feel for the subsampling rate that is needed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! I will look into it!

As for the "full list of human-readable categories" are these the stuff the model is trained to detect? Because, interestigly enough, "keys" isn't there :P

Comment: Hmmm. That's funny. If you really wanted to make a key detector, you could  use [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) simple method to adapt the inception network. But hopefully "keys" was just an unfortunate choice of example.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of making that a "feature" of the system anyway, to add a funcionality of "find _my_ keys" instead of "find _any_ keys"